# How to calculate the Jacobian of a vector function with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. I would like to know what's wrong with the following code to calculate a Jacobian:

```
w1, w2 = tf.Variable(1.), tf.Variable(1.)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    z1 = w1*w2 + w1**2
    z2 = w1 + w2
    
tape.jacobian(tf.Variable([z1, z2]), [w1, w2])  

# output: [None, None]
```

where I expect a 2x2 matrix from the definition of the Jacobian of a vector function:

```
[[dz1/dw1, dz1/dw2], [dz2/dw1, dz2/dw2]] = [[3,1],[1,1]]
```

but the result is [None, None]

Comment: Your tape.jacobian(..) is outside with scope "with .... as tape", is that also in your code?

Comment: if I put tape.jacobian(..) inside with-scope then I get the error "ValueError: Tape is still recording, This can happen if you try to re-enter an already-active tape."

Comment: as ok very interesting I have never seen such scoped variables that you use after they exit

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
w1, w2 = tf.Variable(1.), tf.Variable(1.)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    z1 = w1*w2 + w1**2
    z2 = w1 + w2

tape.jacobian(z1, (w1, w2))
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>)

tape.jacobian(z2, (w1, w2))
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>)
```

Comment: The same result can be obtained using tape.gradient(z1, (w1,w2)), tape.gradient(z2, (w1,w2)). Then what's the point of there being jacobian()?